# How to run a python script in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am new to Django, and I'm trying to import one of my models in a script as we do it in views.py. I'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "CallCenter\make_call.py", line 3, in <module>

    from .models import Campaign


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.models'; '__main__' is not a package
```

My file structure is like:

MyApp\CallCenter\

CallCenter contains `__init__.py`, `make_call.py`, `models.py`, `views.py` and MyApp has `manage.py`

```py
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse, Say, Dial, Number, VoiceResponse
from .models import Campaign


def create_xml():

    # Creates XML
    response = VoiceResponse()
    campaign = Campaign.objects.get(pk=1)
    response.say(campaign.campaign_text)

    return response


xml = create_xml()
print(xml)
```

Comment: How are you invoking `make_call.py`? `python make_call.py` within the `CallCenter` app directory won't work.

Comment: @AKX I ran (venv) C:\Users\Username\PycharmProjects\MyApp>python CallCenter\make_call.py

Comment: You can't just run a python file inside a Django project as if it were any python script: There's a whole setup Django does to load your apps and models (`django.setup()`) which is required to be able to use your models etc... If you want to run a command-line like script using Django, create a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) so you can run it with `manage.py` which will do the proper setup for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, it's better to refactor "ad-hoc" scripts – anything you might run manually from a command line, say – into [management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/).

That way the Django runtime is set up correctly once things get to your code, and you get command-line parsing for free too.

Your `make_call.py` might become something like this:

## CallCenter/management/commands/make_call.py

```py
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse, Say, Dial, Number, VoiceResponse
from CallCenter.models import Campaign

from django.core.management import BaseCommand


def create_xml(campaign):
    # Creates XML
    response = VoiceResponse()
    response.say(campaign.campaign_text)
    return response


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument("--campaign-id", required=True, type=int)

    def handle(self, campaign_id, **options):
        campaign = Campaign.objects.get(pk=campaign_id)
        xml = create_xml(campaign)
        print(xml)
```

and it would be invoked with

```
$ python manage.py make_call --campaign-id=1
```

from wherever your `manage.py` is.

(Remember to have an `__init__.py` file in both the `management/` and the `management/commands/` folders.)